# Gmail like Drag and Drop File Upload

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, asp.net-ajax

How can I do Gmail like drag and drop attachment upload with asp.net and jQuery? If that's not possible with current HTML version or the platforms I mentioned do we have any other alternative?

Comment: This isn't something you can do with just those tools, it relies on HTML5 features.

Comment: I don't think so the newer version of gmail is using HTML 5

Comment: That's *exactly* my point :) For example IE8 doesn't have file drag/drop support in gmail, since it doesn't support most HTML5 features.

Comment: ok if i want to do it in HTML 5 and Javascript how shall i start with it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/fileapi) will help you. However, expect to work only on real browsers (so IE is excluded!)